# Using MySQL, How to Set Unique Sequence Number WITHIN a Group

Tags: mysql, grouping, sequence

How can I create an UPDATE statement using MySQL to set a unique sequential value WITHIN clusters / groups of records?

I have a table with columns for UniqueID, State ("AL", "CA", etc.), PersonName, and StateID.  I need to number the StateID for each person *starting at 1 for each State*.

Here is my setup:

```
CREATE TABLE MyData( UniqueID VARCHAR(64), State VARCHAR(64), PersonName VARCHAR(64), StateID INT );
INSERT INTO MyData VALUES ( UUID(), 'CA', 'David', NULL ), ( UUID(), 'CA', 'Ann', NULL ), ( UUID(), 'CA', 'Bob', NULL ),
                          ( UUID(), 'AL', 'Mary', NULL ), ( UUID(), 'AL', 'Tom', NULL ), ( UUID(), 'AL', 'Evelyn', NULL );
```

I would like StateID to start at 1 and increment for each record WITHIN EACH STATE, but then RESET to 1 for EACH NEW STATE.  The sequencing does NOT have to be alphabetical.

Desired outcome:

```
someIDvalue AL Mary   1
someIDvalue AL Tom    2
someIDvalue AL Evelyn 3
someIDvalue CA David  1
someIDvalue CA Ann    2
someIDvalue CA Bob    3
```

So far I am able to do this:

```
    UPDATE MyData
INNER JOIN (    SELECT UniqueID, (SELECT @RowNumber := @RowNumber +1) NewStateID
                  FROM MyData
            INNER JOIN ( SELECT @RowNumber := 0 ) InternalVariable
              ORDER BY MyData.State ) ReorderedSet ON MyData.UniqueID = ReorderedSet.UniqueID
       SET MyData.StateID = ReorderedSet.NewStateID;
```

But this doesn't reset the sequencing when the state changes.

I don't think using GROUP works because I don't need aggregation - only to know when the state changes from the previous record.

Any help on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for voting to close your question earlier. I misunderstood it and thought you wanted an auto-increment to do this in an ongoing way. If you just want to UPDATE the existing rows, I have a solution that depends on the window function feature in MySQL 8.0. Are you using MySQL 8.0? You can check with `SELECT VERSION();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following MySQL query to set a unique sequential value within clusters/groups of records

`SET @row_number:=0; SET @state:=''; UPDATE MyData SET StateID = (@row_number:=CASE WHEN @state=State THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END)  AND @state:=State ORDER BY State, PersonName;`

This query will reset the sequencing when the state changes. The @row_number variable is used to keep track of the sequence number and the @state variable is used to keep track of the current state. The ORDER BY clause is used to order the records by state and person name.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Variables work in MySQL 5.x, but are now deprecated in MySQL 8.x (though they can be enabled).

Comment: Thank you very much:... I had to change the initial SET @state:=(SELECT State FROM MyData ORDER BY State LIMIT 1); ..... and the "AND" is skewing the logic in the UPDATE statement; however if I replace it with a comma (which seems more sensible to me), there is an error.  Any other advice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Most or all your seven answers from the last two days appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues. m

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to @Adesegun Daniel; here is a slight modification which ended up being a definitive solution.

```
SET @row_number:=0; 
SET @state:=(SELECT State FROM MyData ORDER BY State LIMIT 1); 
UPDATE MyData SET MyData.StateID = (@row_number:= CASE WHEN @state=State THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END), State = (@state := State) 
ORDER BY State, UniqueID;
```